# Non-specificity of voice recognition for voice assistance devices or features

Tags: design-patterns, voice, voice-control

I remember from quite some time ago when Siri was first launched that there was no specific way of getting the voice-triggered assistant to recognize specific voices.

These days there are many different home assistant devices like Amazon Alex and Google Home, and some information is provided in terms of setting up [voice profiles](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GYCXKY2AB2QWZT2X) and training it to [recognize different voices](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/9071681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en-GB) through linking of accounts.

However, I wonder if there is a specific reason why the user experience of setting up voice recognition isn't as easy as other biometric information like finger print or facial recognition. Is this because the technology isn't as mature or that people don't use it as much as other types of biometric?

Are there good examples of design patterns for enabling better specificity of voice recognition where voice control is the dominant way of interacting with a system/application?

**UPDATE**: It seems like these days there are [voice matching procedures](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/9071681?sjid=16333799910151173602-AP#vm_pr&zippy=%2Cvoice-match-personal-results%2Chow-voice-match-works) for mobile devices as biometric security technology improves.

Comment: I think this is more of a technical limitation rather than a UX issue. The last time I looked into voice recognition it was described as being a difficult and complex problem to resolve technically. It is much easier to do when you have a predetermined phrase to match, which it seems some voice assistance are starting to make use of to identify who has initiated the command. I expect if/when the technical limitations are resolved then the application of them will follow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has been answered with update on technology for feature